# Why text-align is applied to span but not img in CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span>Today is Nick's birthday </span>
  <img id="bff-img" src="nick.jpg">
  <h2>24 years old</h2>
  <h4>01.11.2022</h4>
</body>
```

Why the span tag is aligned but not img tag?
As far as I know the text-align CSS property sets the horizontal alignment of the inline-level content inside a block element or table-cell box.

Please explain

Comment: The *img* is aligned. It's part of the inline level box that the span is part of, and is centred with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span>Today is Nick's birthday </span>
  <br />
  <img id="bff-img" src="nick.jpg">
  <h2>24 years old</h2>
  <h4>01.11.2022</h4>
</body>
```

Your code is fine, and the image is centered alongside all other inline elements of `body`, your problem is putting image adjacent to an inline element which is preventing image to be alone in a row (so you can see it centered), expected behavior could be achieved just by a tiny `br` element after and probably before img element which is easiest and Not the best solution

Another way that you can achieve this, (best solution from my opinion) is to put your image in a wrapping `div` and assign the `text-align` to that div, in this scenario you can have even more control over your image using that parent div,

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
   .img-wrapper { text-align : center ;}
```

```html
<body>
  <span>Today is Nick's birthday </span>
  <div class="img-wrapper" >
    <img id="bff-img" src="nick.jpg"> 
  </div>
  <h2>24 years old</h2>
  <h4>01.11.2022</h4>
</body>
```

Body's text-align is not required in this scenario, I've kept it in case you want other element to be centered

Comment: Doesn't need an extra wrapper - `display: block; margin: auto;` for the image also does the trick.

Comment: ```in this scenario you can have even more control over your image using that parent div``` , yes it does the trick but placing much of elements adjacent to each other is not a good idea, it makes hard future maintenance and development. wrapping image in another container gives the opportunity to select it correctly in future using both js and css without effecting other adjacent elements...